# How can I find the limit of the following sequence $\sin ^2 (\pi \sqrt{n^2 + n})$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I  find the limit of the following sequence:
 $$\sin ^2 (\pi \sqrt{n^2 + n})$$

I feel that I will use the identity $$\sin ^2 (\pi \sqrt{n^2 + n}) = \frac{1}{2}(1- \cos(2 \pi \sqrt{n^2 + n})), $$

But then what? how can I deal with the limit of $\cos (2 \pi \sqrt{n^2 + n})$? I know that $\cos (n\pi) = (-1)^n$, if $n$ is a positive integer but then what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuitively, $n^2+n$ is almost exactly halfway between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$, and so $\sqrt{n^2+n}$ is very close to a half-integer. This means $\sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n})$ should be very close to $\pm 1$, and in either case $\sin^2(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n})$ will be very nearly $1$.

More formally, we have
$$\sin^2(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n})=\sin^2[\pi(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n)]
$$
Now, multiplying by $1$ in the form $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}$ gives

$$
\sin^2[\pi(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n)]=\sin^2\left(\pi\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}\right)
$$

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin^2$ is continuous, this sequence has limit $\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{2}=1$.

Comment: I could not understand the first line in your answer .... could you clarify please?

Comment: $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$, so the midpoint between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ is $\frac{2n^2+2n+1}{2}=n^2+n+\frac{1}{2}$. So $n^2+n$ is "very close" to the midpoint. This isn't intended to be rigorous (though you could make it rigorous if you wanted), just a slightly simpler reason for you to believe that the rigorous argument which follows is on the right track.

Comment: But we have a square root.

Comment: Right. And because $n^2+n$ is almost exactly halfway between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$, $\sqrt{n^2+n}$ is almost exactly halfway between $n$ and $n+1$ (that is, it's nearly a half-integer). For example, $\sqrt{1000^2+1000}=1000.499875...$

Answer (score 4):

*Assuming that you want to know more than the limit itself.*

Using $$\sin ^2 (\pi \sqrt{n^2 + n}) = \frac{1}{2}(1- \cos(2 \pi \sqrt{n^2 + n}))$$ use Taylor series 
$$\sqrt{n^2 + n}=n+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$2\pi\sqrt{n^2 + n}=(2n+1)\pi -\frac{\pi}{4 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\cos(2 \pi \sqrt{n^2 + n})\sim -\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4 n}\right)=-1+\frac{\pi ^2}{32 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$\sin ^2 (\pi \sqrt{n^2 + n}) =1-\frac{\pi ^2}{64 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ then the limit and how it is approached.

Using $n=1000$, the "exact" value would be $$\sin ^2\left(10 \sqrt{10010} \pi \right)\approx 0.99999984594$$ while the above approximation would give
$$1-\frac{\pi ^2}{64000000}\approx 0.99999984578$$

Answer (score 1):

You can check $\sin^2(\pi\sqrt{n^2 + n})=\sin^2(\pi\sqrt{n^2 + n}-\pi n)$.
So $$\sin^2(\pi\sqrt{n^2 + n})=\sin^2 \pi\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}+n}\to \sin^2\frac{\pi}{2}=1.$$